# How to tackle an Index Error in my code for finding ORFs

Tags: python, orf

I have created a python code that prints out all lengths of ORFs in a DNA sequence (start codon - "ATG", stop codons - "TAG", "TAA" and "TGA". It seems to give correct answers, when compared with specialized ORF-finding programs. The thing is that besides correct answers it also gives an Index Error in the end:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts.py", line 33, in <module>
    if list_start[i]>list_stop[n-1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Now, I have created a dictionary from a FASTA file where *key* is a sequence name and *value* is the sequence itself and want to find ORFs for all sequences in that dictionary using a *for* loop and this code. However, the loop runs only once and I think that the Index Error to be the cause.

The code is the following:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
line="TCGGGCGAAGGCGGCAGCAAGTCGTCCACGCGCAGCGCGGCACCGCGGGCCTCTGCCGTGCGCTGCTTGGCCATGGCCTCCAGCGCACCGATCGGATCAAAGCCGCTGAAGCCTTCGCGCATCAGGCGGCCATAGTTGGCGCCAGTGACCGTACCAACCGCCTTGATGCGGCGCTCGGTCATCGCTGCATTGATCGAGTAGCCACCGCCGCCGCAAATGCCCAGCACGCCAATGCGTTCTTCATCCACATAGGGGAGCGTTACGAGGTAGTCGCAGACCACGCGGAAATCCTCGACGCGCAGTGTCGGGTCTTCGGTAAAACGTGGTTCGCCGCCGCTGGCACCCTGGAAGCTGGCGTCGAAGGCGATGACGACGAAACCTTCCTTGGCCAGCGCCTCGCCATACACGTTCCCCGATGTTTGCTCCTTGCAGCTGCCGATCGGATGCGCGCTGATGATGGCGGGATATTTCTTGCCTTCGTCGAAGTTCGGCGGGAAGTGGATGTCGGCTGCGATATCCCAATACACATTCTTGATCTTGACGCTTTTCATGACAGCTCCGTTCAGGGGGAGGGGGTAAGTTCGCCAGGCCGAATCGTTGGTAGCCAAGCGGCAACGACTCGAATATAGAGAGCCGATTGGAATTCCGTAAGATCGCAATCTGGACTACAGTGGTATCTTCAAATTGACAATGGCACCTACATGGATCCCTCACTGCTTCCGTCTCTCGCGTGGTTCGCCCACGTCGCACATCATCGTAGCTTCACGAAAGCGGCTGCGGAAATGGGCGTTTCTCGAGCAAACCTGTCGCAGAACGTGAAGGCGCTCGAACGCCGGTTGAACGTCAAGCTGCTGTATCGAACGACTCGCGACATGTCGCTGACCGAGGAGGGGCAGCGGCTCTACGAGGTGTGGTATCCCGCGCTGGTCGCGGTCGAGCGGACGGTCGACGCGCTGCACGAGGAGCGCGACGAGCCGTCGGGGTTGATTC"
r_frame=input('Enter a reading frame')
line=line[int(r_frame)-1:]
# making list of codons (3-nucleotide groups)
x=3
codon=[line[y-x:y] for y in range(x, len(line)+x,x)]
#defininig function  that will find all the indexes of codon in list of codons
def find_indices(list_to_check, item_to_find):
    indices = []
    for idx, value in enumerate(codon):
        if value == item_to_find:
            indices.append(idx)
    return indices
# makirng list with all the indexes of "ATG" (start codon)
list_start=find_indices(codon, "ATG")
#making list with all the indexes of "TGA", "TAA" or "TAG" (stop codons) and sorting it from smaller to bigger
list_stop=find_indices(codon, "TGA")+find_indices(codon, "TAA")+find_indices(codon, "TAG")
list_stop.sort()
i=0 # variable for indexes in list_start
n=0 #variable for indexes in list_stop
j=0 # variable that determines numer of times searching for ORF will be repeated
#first round without loop so that i and n will be >0 and we can make  if list_start[i]>list_stop[n-1] without errors
if list_start[i]<list_stop[n]:
    print(3*(list_stop[n]-list_start[i])+3)
    j=j+1
    n=n+1
    i=i+1
else:
    n=n+1
#loop that will search for suitable start codon-stop codon pairs and print the length of ORF
while j<codon.count('ATG'):
    if list_start[i]>list_stop[n-1]:
        if list_start[i]<list_stop[n]:
            print(3*(list_stop[n]-list_start[i])+3) 
#multiply by 3 'cause one item in list stands for 3 nucleotides and add 3 so the whole length of stop codon will be counted
            j=j+1
            n=n+1
            i=i+1
        else:
            n=n+1
    else: i=i+1
```

For sequence given in the code the ORFs lengths should be as following:

Reading frame 1:63; 36; 36; 213; 129

Reading frame 2: 39

Reading frame 3: 186

This code might seem weird as I'm new to python and bioinformatics. I will be very thankful if anyone gives me an advice how can I get rid of the Index Error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, there is a bug in the code,

Original,

```
def find_indices(list_to_check, item_to_find):
    indices = []
    for idx, value in enumerate(codon):
        if value == item_to_find:
            indices.append(idx)
    return indices
```

Corrected,

```
def find_indices(list_to_check, item_to_find):
    indices = []
    for idx, value in enumerate(list_to_check):
        if value == item_to_find:
            indices.append(idx)
    return indices
```

You renamed the variable `codon` for the function, but then retained its name as `codon` within the function. It should be `list_to_check`. Also it is convenient.

If you are *certain* your code is fine, the easiest way to silence the error is via a `try` and `except` statement. The critical variable is `line` and I'm not sure where that is being declared. Without that its difficult to unpick the underlying error, which is an out of range error.

```
def find_indices(list_to_check, item_to_find):
        indices = []
        for idx, value in enumerate(list_to_check):
            if value == item_to_find:
                indices.append(idx)
        return indices


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #line= sample DNA nucleotide sequence

    try:
        r_frame= input('Enter a reading frame')
        line = line[int(r_frame)-1:]
        line=line[int(r_frame)-1:]
        x=3
        codon=[line[y-x:y] for y in range(x, len(line)+x,x)]
        list_start=find_indices(codon, "ATG")
        list_stop=find_indices(codon, "TGA")+find_indices(codon, "TAA")+find_indices(codon, "TAG")
        list_stop.sort()
        i=0 # variable for indexes in list_start
        n=0 #variable for indexes in list_stop
        j=0 # variable that determines numer of times searching for ORF will be repeated
        if list_start[i]<list_stop[n]:
            print(3*(list_stop[n]-list_start[i])+3)
            j=j+1
            n=n+1
            i=i+1
        else:
            n=n+1
        while j<codon.count('ATG'):
            if list_start[i]>list_stop[n-1]:
                if list_start[i]<list_stop[n]:
                    print(3*(list_stop[n]-list_start[i])+3)
                    j=j+1
                    n=n+1
                    i=i+1
                else:
                    n=n+1
            else:
                i = i + 1
    except AssertionError as error:
        print (error)
    except:
        pass
```

If you want to see the error you simply deleted the late two lines of code.

**However*** to resolve the second bug is quite complicated, particularly without a `line` declaration. We would simply use is `Biopython`'s `.translate()` method, we wouldn't do this from first principles. In a past question thats been done.